# How to call javascript one page to another?

Tags: javascript

Hi i am trying to call javascript  from one page to anothrt but i am not able to get that how can i make it.

Here is my script

```
demo1.php   
if(i==j){       
    <script>
        function deeletconfig(){

    var del=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
    if (del==true){
       alert ("record deleted")
    }else{
        alert("Record Not Deleted")
    }
    return del;
    }
}
else
{
alert("bye");
}
</script>
```

Here is my another file

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="val_skill">No of Room<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<div class="col-md-6" id="txtHint">
<select id="noofroom" name="noofroom" class="form-control" onchange="deleletconfig(); ">

</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Here i am trying to cal this script  on  onchange but it is not working here

How can i achive my output

Thanks

Comment: both files are php file?

Answer (score 0):

Use Code This :-

Remove Condition

```
if(i==j){
```

From File demo1.php  and add script like this

```
  <script>
        function deeletconfig(){

    var del=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
    if (del==true){
       alert ("record deleted")
    }else{
        alert("Record Not Deleted")
    }
    return del;
    }
}
else
{
alert("bye");
}
</script>
```

and this function will work where you will include demo1.php.

Answer (score 0):

Make it into an external script and include it in both files

```
<script src="your-script.js"></script>
```

`your-script.js` contains everything from within your `<script>` tags